# Can you do ST_Transform on geographies?

Tags: postgis

I am brand new to postgis. I just learned that geometries model simple cartesian objects and that geographies model shapes on the surface of the earth. I have a bunch of data in columns X and Y of a table -- where X and Y are state plane coordinates in a medium-sized US city.

It seems  like you use `ST_Point()` to get the coordinates into a point and then `ST_SetSRID` to get them into a certain coordinate system and then [ST_Tranform](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Transform.html) to get them into a lat/long format. But these are points on the surface of the earth -- so I really want a want a geography not a geometry, right?

Am I describing the correct method to do this? Do you do ST_Transform on geometries only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

Geography is going to mean more processor expensive calculations, but it's much simpler to use.

ST_Point takes a x & y that can be measure in degrees, but is only 2D , and the setting the SRID is, as you said, expresses the system that the co-ordinates are in.

The ST_Transform is about converting from the 2D Plane - geometry - into the 3D Spherical representation -  the geography type.

This is a great resource on it all, and what to chose.

http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html

Oh and geography also can have a z component too, height above ground.